# how to show hide the image in jquery

Tags: jquery

html code:

```
<div class="largeimg">

<a class="slide-image"  href="javascript:void(0);"">
<img  src="200944393_aboutus.jpg">
</a>
<a class="slide-image"  href="javascript:void(0);"">
<img  src="200944393_aboutus_1.jpg">
</a>
<a class="slide-image"  href="javascript:void(0);"">
<img  src="200944393_aboutus_2.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

right:

```
 <div class="thumbimg">

    <a class="thumb-image"  href="javascript:void(0);"">
    <img  src="200944393_aboutus.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="thumb-image"  href="javascript:void(0);"">
    <img  src="200944393_aboutus_1.jpg">
    </a>
    <a class="thumb-image"  href="javascript:void(0);"">
    <img  src="200944393_aboutus_2.jpg">
    </a>
    </div>
```

the three thumb line in vertical,
when the mouse hover on the thumb image. on the left shows its large image according.other two large image are hidden.

jquery code:

```
$(".largeimg a").hide();
$(".largeimg a:eq(1)").show();

$('.thumbimg a').on({
    'hover': function() {
         var src = $(this).attr('src');

         $(".largeimg img").attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

it's not right. how to correct it?thank u.

Comment: I don not understand. What is the question? And what has rotate to do with showing or hiding a picture?

Comment: href="javascript:void(0);"" <- there is an error here (x6), double ".
And all those (  href="javascript:void(0);"") are useless ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the source from the wrong element. In your `hover` function you are getting the source from the `a` tag rather than the image inside, so you need to do this:

```
$(".largeimg a").hide();
$(".largeimg a:eq(1)").show();

$('.thumbimg a').on({
    'hover': function() {
         // Getting the source of the image, rather than source of hovered element.
         var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
         $(".largeimg img").attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, your HTML is invalid. You have to many double quotes:

```
<a class="thumb-image"  href="javascript:void(0);"">
```

should be

```
<a class="thumb-image"  href="javascript:void(0);">
```

And to add to it, `img` is self-closing so it should be `<img  src="200944393_aboutus_2.jpg" />`

Comment: hi,now i want to add a class to .thumbimg a. i use     $(this).addClass('current'); in the hover function. why it not work. thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on image which you want to rotate

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#image").rotate({angle:45});
 });
```

Comment: you can adjust the  angel as per your requirement

Comment: I think you need to have an extra plugin for this. It won't work with jQuery out of the box.